# Python data descriptor did not work as instance variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, descriptor

As the official demo described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example), the following code will print `Retrieving var "x"`.

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print 'Retrieving', self.name
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print 'Updating', self.name
        self.val = val


class MyClass1(object):
    x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')

MyClass1().x
```

But if `x` is an instance variable, the data descriptor machinery will not work, the following code will not print anything.

```
class MyClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')

MyClass2().x
```

And, if I implements the data descriptor machinery manually as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors), the following code will `Retrieving var "x"` again.

```
class MyClass3(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        "Emulate type_getattro() in Objects/typeobject.c"
        v = object.__getattribute__(self, key)
        if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
            return v.__get__(None, self)
        return v

MyClass3().x
```

So, is the default data descriptor machinery not implemented as the doc described?

I am using python 2.7.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The descriptor how-to is wrong here. The [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) has the correct description:

> The following methods [`__get__`, `__set__`, and `__delete__`] only apply when an instance of the class
>   containing the method (a so-called descriptor class) appears in an
>   owner class (the descriptor must be in either the owner’s class
>   dictionary or in the class dictionary for one of its parents).

Descriptors have to be class attributes.